# Get the value in Javascript from wordpress video URL field (in JW Player script)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube, jwplayer

I have a Wordpress theme called Aruna (mostrly for videos) . In the post editor once I want to make a video I have just to paste the YouTube URL into the field and publish it.

I want to integrate the JW player (instead of the YouTube player) automatically in all my posts already published.

There is no problem to load the video if put this code in the post text content:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CjdLYBDUqw",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
```

Everything's fine with that code. It loads the YouTube video with the JW player.

I want to edit the `content-video.php` (which is the video section of the post) and make it able to pick the url from the same field I use normally.

With Firebug I could see the name of the field in the editor which is:

```
<input type="text" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8k20kHZjug" id="_video_externalvideo" name="_video_externalvideo" class="cmb_oembed">
```

Here inside the `content-video.php` as default, it picks up the URL by php:

```
<?php } 
            if( (isset($externalvideo) && $externalvideo != '') || (isset($localvideo) && $localvideo != '') ) { ?>
                <div class="video-wrap">
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($externalvideo) && $externalvideo != '') {
                        if(isset($GLOBALS['wp_embed'])) {
                            $embed = $GLOBALS['wp_embed']->autoembed($externalvideo);
                            $embed = str_replace("feature=oembed", "feature=oembed&amp;wmode=transparent", $embed);
                            echo $embed;
                        }
                    }
                    elseif(isset($localvideo) && $localvideo != '') { 
                        echo apply_filters('the_content', '[video width="650" height="360" src="' . $localvideo . '"]');
                    }
                    ?>
```

I suppose I shuold get rid of that php code and change it with:

```
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CjdLYBDUqw",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
```

My question is: how can I edit the script in the part:

```
file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8k20kHZjug"
```

into something automatic able to pick up the URL from the same field as I used in a default video post?

Should I use a php function inside the script or just a javascript function?

I tried everything, nothing has worked so far. I don't know so much about `php` and `javascript`.

I hope one of you can help me.

I felt to get close to the solution with this:

```
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: function 
      .getElementById("_video_externalvideo"),
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Alex

Here how `$externalvideo` is defined inside `content-video.php`:

```
<?php global $redux_demo; $localvideo = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video_localvideo', true); $externalvideo = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video_externalvideo', true); $nsfw = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video_nsfw', true); if(is_user_logged_in() ) { $userid = wp_get_current_user(); if(get_user_meta($userid->ID, '_nsfw', true) != 1) { $nsfw = 2; } } $class = 'main-post'; if(is_single() ) { $class .= ' post-page'; } ?>
```

**UPDATE: Thanks to @SilverKenn for the useful answer,**
I didn't resolve the problem yet but we are getting closer to the solution.
I put the php code in my template but at the end it has been read like this:

```
<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true">jwplayer("player-viralizzato").setup({
    file:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txPQC8NB_-M,
    width: 640,
    height: 360
});</script>
```

instead of:

```
<script>jwplayer("player-viralizzato").setup({
    file:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txPQC8NB_-M",
    width: 640,
    height: 360
});</script>
```

If I edit in Firebug the code:
`<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true">` to `<script>`
AND
`file:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txPQC8NB_-M,` to `file:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txPQC8NB_-M",`
it would be working propely, any idea?
Thanks again

Comment: Please, show how `$externalvideo` is defined inside `content-video.php`

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this?

Comment: Here how $externalvideo is defined inside content-video.php:
<?php
global $redux_demo;
$localvideo = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video_localvideo', true);
$externalvideo = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video_externalvideo', true);
$nsfw = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video_nsfw', true);
if(is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $userid = wp_get_current_user();
    if(get_user_meta($userid->ID, '_nsfw', true) != 1) {
        $nsfw = 2;
    }
}
$class = 'main-post';
if(is_single() ) {
    $class .= ' post-page';
}
?>

Comment: and here is a sample of the page: 
http://ipnovideo.com/pubblicita-birra-carlsberg-al-cinema-pieno-di-motociclisti/

Comment: Syntax error. file: ,,

Comment: Can you please explain better where should I edit the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the video url is already on the page where you want to display the Player,

you can simply use Jquery like this,

```
(function($){ 

    // Get the video URL
    var video_uri = $('#_video_externalvideo').val();

    jwplayer('myElement').setup({
        file: '"' +video_uri + '"',
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });

})(jQuery)
```

Or Use PHP in your template

```
$externalvideo = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video_externalvideo', true);
echo '<script>'."\n";
echo "\t".'jwplayer("myElement").setup({'."\n"; 
echo "\t\t".'file:"'.$externalvideo.'",'."\n";   
echo "\t\t".'width: 640,'."\n"; 
echo "\t\t".'height: 360'."\n"; 
echo "\t".'});'."\n";
echo '</script>'."\n";
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the useful answer. 
I didn't fix the problem yet but we are getting closer. 
I got an UPDATE in my question with the problem still to adjust. If you have the solution it would be great, thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you tell me if you are using php or jquery? I can't see any reason why `type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true"` is being added on your code, mind showing your whole code to display the script

Comment: I have already tried @silver's answer on similar lines but for angular2+typescript based application. Even though this hides video url from javascript, once the web page is rendered in the browser the video url will be visible under myElement tag.

Just go to tools->inspect element and you will see what I mean to say